# I cannot run my app on my iOS devices even though they are updated

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Recently I've updated my software on my iPhone (iOS 12.1). I'm using Xcode 10.1 and my MacBook software version is MacOS Mojave 10.14. (MacBook Air)

The point is that all my software is updated and I can't get rid of an annoying bug that says:

> "Could not locate device support files".

Screenshot:

[image]

I have already tried to clean the project and to delete derived data, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you installed XCode 10.1?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you should update Xcode to the latest one (it might be Xcode beta).

but, if you can not update Xcode due to some reason follow following steps listed here: https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

1. Select and download the Support files which are missing for your Xcode (12.1 (16B5059d).zip):
   https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/12.1%20(16B5059d).zip
2. Unzip it;
3. Close Xcode;
4. Copy and paste unziped folder by path: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/"
5. Reopen Xcode;

Comment: @RaoulBocancea you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.